# Time from core 2.3.0 vs from stdlib 2.5.3

Tags: ruby

I'm a little confused with Ruby documentation on https://ruby-doc.org/. We can find there [`Time` class as a part of core 2.3.0](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-i-zone), where we have 60 functions described, and also [`Time` class as a part of stdlib 2.5.3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html), where we have only 13. Does these descriptions describe the same class? Are both actual for Ruby 2.5.3? Which of these descriptions should I trust?

Comment: The docs from stdlib are pretty clear: _"When 'time' is required, Time is extended with additional methods for parsing and converting Times."_. So yes, these are two different things: the core `Time` class and some add-ons from stdlib.

Comment: Regarding the two versions: ruby-doc.org hosts docs for several Ruby versions. You should probably use the one matching _your_ Ruby version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is both a [core Time library](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Time.html#method-i-zone) and a [stdlib Time library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html).

Core one implements the core functionality of Time. Its structures, basic math, time zones, and generic formatting functions. Stdlib adds additional convenience methods for parsing and formatting.

I can only guess why from my own experience with dates and times. There are *a lot* of date and time formats and they can rapidly bloat out an otherwise simple library both for memory and complexity. I presume the Ruby folks wanted to keep core `Time` simple and made the extra formatting optional.

`Time` does have a few formatting functions like `asctime`, `ctime`, and `strftime`. These you get for free from C, and `strftime` is quite powerful.

Comment: It is really odd that `Time` exists by default and `require 'time'` adds more methods to `Time`, but that's how it is.